# How to control the output of an ^ (XOR) operation to fall between expected range?

Tags: python, xor

I am trying to create a python script with intakes a string which strictly contains digits or upper case or lower case alphabets. `650XYZ000X34` is an example input.

Now, I want to replace each character of the input with a character from the range A to B and each digit with the range 0 to 9 in a way so that the output looks un-relatable. Not necessarily replace an alphabet with an alphabet and digit with a digit but **I want the output to strictly contain characters within range 0 to 9, upper case A to Z and smaller case a to z**.

I figured out the doing an XOR operation on each character could potentially achieve my goal since the XOR would make something out of something which makes the output look hugely un-relatable. So I wrote the following code.

```
# Input to the script is not longer than 12 characters
import sys

def myxor(s1, s2):
    a_list = [chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s1, s2)]
    return "".join(a_list)

input = str(sys.argv[1])
secret = myxor('MySaLtToTestSomething', input)
print("The secret key computed is: " + secret)
```

But the problem above is that it `650XYZ000X34` outputs `et|`. The output is small as well as containing **special characters which I don't want**. Is there a way to make the method `myxor` replace each character of the input with either a digit between 0 to 9 or an alphabet from upper case A to Z or smaller case a to z? Some kind of a controlled XOR operation?

Comment: Expand out the list comprehension into a for statement then you can add debugging print statements...

Comment: What is the first character of your string ord(‘6’) and what is first character of salt ord(‘S’). Now do the arithmetic and xor them, what’s the result? Also what is the result of `zip()` when the salt runs out (four characters)?

Comment: Good point. The Salt needS to be a long string so that it does not run out of characters. May the same length as input for simplicity.

Comment: do the xor as you did, then send it to a function that send it to the relevant Unicode range, for example  if num<48 return chr(int(num/5+48)) which will bring you to 1-9 chars

Comment: @trigonom Do you mind putting that into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output seems to be fine

```
for a, b in zip('SaLt','650XYZ000X34'):
    print (a,b,'-->',chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)))

S 6 --> e
a 5 --> T
L 0 --> |
t X --> ,
```

Remember that zip only matches up the smallest of the two strings, the rest of the unmatched longer string ignored.

**Now to make the output fall in range, you can try something like this:**

```
for a, b in zip('SaLt','650XYZ000X34'):
    xor=ord(a) ^ ord(b)
    while True:
      if xor<65:    
         xor=xor%10  # selects a number between 48 and 57
         i=48
         break
      if xor<97:
         xor=xor%26   # selects a number between 65 and 90
         i=65
         break
      xor=xor%26      # selects a number between 97 and 122
      i=97
      break         
    print (a,b,'-->',chr(i+xor))
```

And your results will be

```
SaLt
S 6 --> x
a 5 --> G
L 0 --> u
t X --> 4

Appalachian  
A 6 --> p
p 5 --> R
p 0 --> 4
a X --> 7
l Y --> 3
a Z --> 9
c 0 --> F
h 0 --> K
i 0 --> L
a X --> 7
n 3 --> P
```

Of course you can change the code to suit your particular environment.

Comment: Trying this out gives me a really good idea of what outputs what. Excellent! Is there a way I can control the output to be between the alphanumeric range?

Comment: I just want to eliminate the special the characters and replace them with something alphanumeric

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg I finished my answer so your output falls in the range expected

Answer (score 2):

Unicode range of your output is 48-57 is 1-9, 65-90 is A-Z, 97-122 is a-z so

```
def toChar(num):
    if 100>num>0:
        if 58>num>47 or 91>num>64 or 123>num>97: # if its in desire output range, return it
            return chr(num)
        return chr(int(num/10+48)) #copy it to 48-57
    if 200>num>99:
        return chr(int(num/4+40)) #copy it to 65-90
    if 300>num>199:
        return chr(int(num/4+47)) # copy it to 97-122
```

i'm not sure what are the possible return value from xor this just covers 1-300
the function works like this,
to copy num from range A to range B
divide num with size ratio
then add the diff

for example
copy from 100-200 to 30-40
first divide by 10 because the range is 10 times bigger
then add 20 to get into the range